# Travel to US two day before B1 visa expires

Tags: usa, b1-b2-visas, visa-extensions

I have a B1 visa which is expire in next 5-10 days and need to travel to US for an urgent assignment. Can I travel just before 2-3 days of my visa expires. Will immigration officer give me I 94 more more than my VISA expiry date. Any Idea?

Comment: Sorry, it's not entirely clear (At least to me) - do you mean you want to travel TO the US 2-3 days before you visa expires, and then....would you leave AFTER it's meant to expire? Or still leave before?

Comment: Yes, enter US 2 days before and leave after visa expires. It depends on what I 94 will be given. But does the immigration officer will give I 94 post visa expiry date?

Comment: Please advice if its good to travel 2 days before visa expiry date or not. My length of start would be 2 weeks. Will Immigration officer provide me I 94 for more than 2 days. Is it clear now?. Appreciate you quick reply.

Comment: @user11726: The I-94 expiration date has absolutely nothing to do with the visa expiration date. The I-94 will probably be for 6 months or however long the officer decides.

Comment: You should check with the airline whether or not they will fly you to the US.  They have discretion to refuse carriage if it has potential to violate visa.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A U.S. visa is only for entering the U.S. You can use it to enter any time before the expiration date. The visa expiration date has no bearing on how long you can stay in the U.S. How long you can stay in the U.S. is the expiration date on the I-94, which is determined by the immigration officer at the border depending on your visa type and other factors (like how much time you've spent in the U.S. recently).

You do not need a valid visa to remain in the U.S.; your status in the U.S. is determined by the I-94. If you are entering by air or sea after May 2013, they do not give out paper I-94s anymore. They stamp the I-94 expiration date next to the entry stamp, and you can (if you wish) look up and print out an I-94 [online](https://i94.cbp.dhs.gov/%E2%80%8E) (but for most visitors that is not necessary).

Comment: Your entry to the US before the visa expiration is totally in the discretion of the Border Control.