# US Visa to renew or not

Tags: visas, usa, b1-b2-visas

My Wife and I have B1/B2 US Visas that expire Sept this year. We took out  visas because our Daughter lives in the States. We usually go for 2 months in the summer and no more than 4 weeks at Christmas time. In total no more than 3 months. Do you suggest we renew our visas or let them expire and use ESTAs in future?
The only problem this year is that we shall go to the States late July and return late Sept which is after the expiry date of our visas!

Comment: It’s not a good idea to publish your real name

Comment: What is the downside to renewing the visas?

Comment: @JonCuster assuming a ten-year visa, roughly $9 a year (a visa costs $160 while five two-year ESTAs cost $70, although under current law the fee is set to drop to $4 from $14 in a little while).  If the traveler is Australian, the difference is greater, since the cost is $160 for a 1-year visa or $185 for a 5-year visa.  I would also ask "what's the downside of using ESTA/VWP?" and "why did you get the visas in the first place?"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Travel to US two day before B1 visa expires](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/24520/travel-to-us-two-day-before-b1-visa-expires)

Comment: @phoog - sure, but I had the (perhaps erroneous) impression that having an actual visa was better than having an ESTA when entering. Compared with the potential costs of not being admitted, it seems fairly straightforward to pay a bit more for fewer headaches. Perhaps I do the calculus differently...

Comment: @JonCuster having a visa is in fact better, but the benefits are negligible to most travelers.  The major benefits are (1) a longer period of admission, and (2) the ability to appeal against an immigration officer's adverse findings (for example, of inadmissibility).  Since OP isn't planning to stay for longer than 90 days in any one visit, the magnitude of the benefit depends on the probability of being found inadmissible.  For most travelers this is extremely unlikely, which is why most people who are eligible use the VWP.

Comment: @phoog - From my perspective in life, having kids and not being too far from retirement, I could easily foresee visits getting longer and/or more frequent. The stage of life of the OP is not quite as clear, but having direct family resident in the US could well shift the balance between ESTA vs visa for at least some. In my situation, I'd go with the visa. Personal choice...

Comment: @JonCuster thanks, that comment reminds me of another benefit that VWP visitors give up: the option of extending their stay or switching to another immigration status without leaving the US.  Someone who wants to keep options open, you are right to point out, should definitely consider using a visa rather than the VWP.

Comment: @phoog Rules have changed.  VWP folks can adjust status now.

Comment: @HonoraryWorldCitizen as far as I'm aware that option is available only to immediate family of US citizens, as an exception to the general prohibition against adjustment of status, and extension of status and change of status (that is, to another nonimmigrant status) continue to be prohibited.  Noting the op's circumstances, it does seem that the parent of an adult child is an immediate relative for this purpose.

Answer (score 3):

If you are eligible for the Visa Waiver Program, and you do not plan on spending more than 90 days at a time in the US, then there is very little reason not to use the VWP. The cost of the required ESTAs is usually lower and there is less paperwork. If in the future you decide you want to spend more than 90 days you can always apply for another visa then.

The expiry date of a US visa is the last day on which you can **enter** the US. Having entered you can stay for as long as the admitting officer gives you, even if your visa expires during that time.

Also, theoretically, there is nothing to stop you entering under the VWP even if you hold a valid visa.

Comment: "it's not unheard of for people to visit Canada for a day and then realize their visa has expired and they can't get back to the US": it *should* be unheard of, however, because of automatic revalidation (info is available from both the [State Department](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/visa-information-resources/visa-expiration-date/auto-revalidate.html) and [CBP](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1218/~/automatic-revalidation-for-certain-temporary-visitors)).  Also, a VWP-eligible traveler ought to be able to re-enter under the VWP after a B visa expires.

Comment: Re last paragraph: Indeed, anecdotal evidence suggests that travelers with VWP country passports _and_ visas will often get admitted under VWP unless they're proactive about pointing out the visa to the border officer when they enter.

Comment: @phoog I've removed the claim, which I only ever intended to be incidental.

Comment: It's still worth noting that such a thing would happen to a B-status visitor who is not eligible for the VWP and goes, for example, to the Caribbean, as automatic revalidation would be unavailable.  But in all of this, I think it's easy to lose site of the most important point, which is that Gerry (OP) *can make the July-to-September trip using the existing visa even though the visa will expire before the end of the trip.*